# Sematext Logagent Elasticsearch - Indexes not being created?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, bro, zeek

I'm trying to send data to Elasticsearch using `logagent` but while there doesn't seem to be any error sending the data, the index isn't being created in ELK. I'm trying to find the index by creating a new index pattern via the Kibana GUI but the index does not seem to exist. This is my `logagent.conf` right now:

```
input:
#  bro-start:
#    module: command
#    # store BRO logs in /tmp/bro in JSON format
#    command: mkdir /tmp/bro; cd /tmp/bro; /usr/local/bro/bin/bro -i eth0 -e 'redef LogAscii::use_json=T;'
#    sourceName: bro
#    restart: 1
  # read the BRO logs from the file system ...
  files:
      - '/usr/local/bro/logs/current/*.log'
parser:
  json:
    enabled: true
    transform: !!js/function >
      function (sourceName, parsed, config) {
        var src = sourceName.split('/')
        // generate Elasticsearch _type out of the log file sourceName
        // e.g. "dns" from /tmp/bro/dns.log
        if (src && src[src.length-1]) {
        parsed._type = src[src.length-1].replace(/\.log/g,'')
        }
        // store log file path in each doc
        parsed.logSource = sourceName
        // convert Bro timestamps to JavaScript timestamps
        if (parsed.ts) {
        parsed['@timestamp'] = new Date(parsed.ts * 1000)
        }
       }
output:
  stdout: false
  elasticsearch:
    module: elasticsearch
    url: http://10.10.10.10:9200
    index: bro_logs
```

Maybe I have to create the index mappings manually? I don't know.

Thank you for any advice or insight!

Answer (score 0):

I found out that there actually was an error . I was trying to send some authentication via a field called "auth" but that doesn't exist. I can do `url: https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@10.10.10.10:9200` though.